# Conditional validation react hook form and zod

Tags: reactjs, react-hook-form, zod

I'm creating multi-step form in React and using React Hook Form and Zod for validation.
To keep it simple, lets assume that I have only two steps and three fields.

Step one:

Select with two options - this field is required.

```
<Select placeholder='Select option' {...register("select")}>
  <option value='A'>Option A</option>
  <option value='B'>Option B</option>
</Select>
```

Step two:

Here are two fields, and its visibility is dependent on value from previous step.

```
{inputOneVisible && <Input placeholder='Input 1' {...register("inputOne")}/>}
{inputTwoVisible && <Input placeholder='Input 2' {...register("inputTwo")}/>}
```

Both of inputs have different validations, but I need to validate only one depending on the param from select. Can such validation be done if I'm using separate schemas per every step of form?

```
export const stepOneSchema = z.object({
  options: z.string()
});
export const stepTwoSchema = z.object({
  input1: z.string(),
  input2: z.string()
});
```

Edit:
I didn't mention that the steps are separate forms managed by a container components which render proper form depending on step number.

Answer (score 0):

Modify your validation schemas and use React Hook Form's watch function to observe changes in the select field

Here's an example :

```
import React from 'react';
import { useForm } from 'react-hook-form';
import { z } from 'zod';
import { zodResolver } from '@hookform/resolvers/zod';

// Step One Schema
const stepOneSchema = z.object({
  select: z.enum(['A', 'B']).nonempty()
});

// Step Two Schema
const stepTwoSchema = z.object({
  inputOne: z.string().optional(),
  inputTwo: z.string().optional()
}).refine(data => {
  if (data.select === 'A') {
    return z.object({
      inputOne: z.string().nonempty("Input 1 is required")
    }).safeParse(data);
  } else if (data.select === 'B') {
    return z.object({
      inputTwo: z.string().nonempty("Input 2 is required")
    }).safeParse(data);
  }
  return true;
});

export default function MyForm() {
  const { register, handleSubmit, watch, formState: { errors } } = useForm({
    resolver: zodResolver(stepOneSchema.merge(stepTwoSchema))
  });

  const selectValue = watch('select');

  const onSubmit = data => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <select {...register('select')} placeholder='Select option'>
        <option value='A'>Option A</option>
        <option value='B'>Option B</option>
      </select>

      {selectValue === 'A' && (
        <input placeholder='Input 1' {...register('inputOne')} />
      )}

      {selectValue === 'B' && (
        <input placeholder='Input 2' {...register('inputTwo')} />
      )}

      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks for fast response! I didn't know about the watch function. But will your example be usable also if I have two steps in separate forms managed by container component, and the state of forms saved in one object using useContext() hook?

Comment: Yes, you can still use this approach with two separate forms managed by a container component and state managed via the useContext hook. In this scenario, you would have a context that holds the state of the forms, and each step would update this shared state. The watch function can still be used to observe changes in form values, but you might need to slightly adjust how you handle the shared state and validation.

Comment: I'm trying to figure it out but don't know how to use in my case,
Could you please give me any advice? I changed your example in [CodeSandbox](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/reverent-mirzakhani-yswwsw)